# Apply CSS Style on condition

Tags: html, css, vb.net

I have a CSS style to make the background gray.

```
.team_not_selected {
    background-color: #B0B0B0;
}
```

I'm displaying data from objects in a table format.

```
<table>
    @For each item in model
    <tr>
        <th>item.Name</th>
        <th>item.ModelNumber</th>
        etc....
        Next
    </tr>
</table>
```

Each object has a variable called "`IsSelected`" which is a Boolean.  I set that variable elsewhere.  I want to apply the `team_not_selected` div to the  tag if `item.IsSelected = False`.  That way, if the record is grayed out if it is not selected.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your code, looks like you want to add all rows as TableHeader (th), please verify.

For conditional CSS, try one of these:

1. IIf condition:

   ```
   <div class="@IIf(item.IsSelected, "team_selected", "team_not_selected")">
   ```
2. If Condition:

   ```
   @If (item.IsSelected) Then
   <div class="team_selected">
   Else 
   <div class="team_not_selected">
   End if
   ```

Comment: Mark it answer then? If it helped you can upvote also